# Extract data to file after performing kriging interpolation in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, export, interpolation, kriging

For 3 meteorological stations, I created maps by Kriging Interpolation tool to extract data for other places. How is it possible to extract a data file (Excel or text) from this interpolation?

(this work is done by ArcGIS9 and Arcmap version 9.3)

Comment: please specify what software you are using. Also, interpolating with 3 points is not very safe.

Comment: Software is ArcGIS9 and Arcmap version 9.3, I don't have any other choice , all I have to do is with these 3 stations

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to get your locations on the map (add XY event layer if you don't already have a shapefile)

Then, you can use "[extract value to point](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=extract_values_to_points)" in order to extract the values that have interpolated.

Finally, you can [export your attribute values to ascii file](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=export_feature_attribute_to_ascii_%28spatial_statistics%29)

Answer (score 1):

Most GIS applications have the ability to convert tabular data that have coordinates columns into an event layer.

For exmaple:

- Using QGIS, add csv to map using the *Add Delimited Text Layer* button
- Using ArcMap, add table to map, right click layer in TOC and select *Display XY Data*

You may then save as or export your event layer to an actual GIS layer (e.g. shapefile or geodatabase feature class), and then run your analysis on that layer.

Answer (score 1):

you can export raster data such as kriging output into a tabular form, but it will list unique values and the number of cells for each value. if this is all you need, you can generate an attribute table using the Build raster attribute table tool in the general\raster\raster properties toolbox. not all raster types are supported, so you might have to do some conversion pre-processing (the copy raster tool would likely help with this). once you have an attribute table, you can export to dbf/text to use in excel.